# POST request to "/" returns a 403 forbidden

Tags: javascript, python, fetch

I am trying to send an a 320 character text post through a POST request to the / route. In that route I have a Twitter-like social network website for making posts and following users. To make and write posts I want it to be asynchronous, i mean, i want the user to write a post and when he presses the button to post it, there shouldn't be a page reload.

This is my html file:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>All Posts</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12 well">
            <form method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
                <textarea class="span11" id="new_message" name="new_message"
                placeholder="Write something nice" rows="5"></textarea>
                <h6 id="characters">320 characters remaining</h6>
                <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Post New Message</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I'm trying to do in JavaScript, but i'm getting a 403:

```
document.querySelector("form").onsubmit = () => {
    //sending values by POST method
  fetch('/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      content: document.querySelector('#new_message').value,
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {

      // Print result
      console.log(result);
    })

  event.preventDefault()
  }


});
```

I'm also not very sure if this is the correct way to do it.

Backend:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        content = request.POST["new_message"]
        print(request.user)
        print(content)
        return render(request, "network/index.html")
        #post = Posts(user=request.user, content=content)
    return render(request, "network/index.html")


def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Attempt to sign user in
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        # Check if authentication successful
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "network/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid username and/or password."
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "network/login.html")


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # Ensure password matches confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, "network/register.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match."
            })

        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, "network/register.html", {
                "message": "Username already taken."
            })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return render(request, "network/register.html")
```

Comment: 403 means forbidden. Without any information it's impossible to know *why* your back end is rejecting the post.

Comment: Can you post the back end code?

Comment: you are not sending the CSRF token

Comment: OK there is the backend code

Comment: @Berto99 How might I go about doing that in the javascript file?

Comment: You aren't passing the CSRF token. You are only passing the textarea. You need to pass the whole form in the request body. Try giving the form an ID and stringify that instead of #new_message.

Comment: @ScottM I've just gave the form an id and replaced the new_message for that id and it is still giving a 403. The 403 pointing to this line  `fetch('/', {`

Answer (score 0):

Since 403 means forbidden I would try to check the permissions of the entity that you are trying to call. Make sure that the proper file has execute permissions from the right level. Check your error log through either apache or other flavor of web server your using and the access log might find something there. Also, in your JS you are logging something to the console, what does JS push to the console?